# Limit Print Quantity in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I am in need of a way that would allow the user print only x number of copies for a document.

For example user clicks on a button and it prints 1 copy of an image. User cannot change the quantity.

This is for a .net web application.

Comment: why is it tagged asp classic?

Comment: If this is for a .NET web application, it shouldn't be tagged for ASP Classic.  These are two different technologies.  Edited.

Comment: Since it all happens on the browser, it has nothing to do with .NET or C# either.

Comment: Why are you trying to limit the print quantity? A user could simply do a screenshot and print that multiple times if they wanted. There's something wrong with your approach if your trying to limit them at the "printing" stage.

Comment: This would have to be done in the browser through html/javascript and has nothing to do with C# or .NET. e.g. `window.print()`  This a function of the browser and there isn't a standard way to ask the browser to limit printing.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. This is what the client wants. Trying to avoid JavaScript, since people can turn off javascript on their browser and do multiple printing. If anybody got a nice idea, may be even third party tools or so I am interested learning about it.

Answer (score 0):

The print quantity of web browsers cannot be scripted.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done cleanly. If nothing else, a user can simply "print once" to a PDF document renderer or other "printer", and the resulting PDF can be printed N times. A user can take a screenshot and print that. Even if you could script against the Print dialog, which you can't, any halfway experienced user will get around it.